# How to uninstall MPICH in linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mpi, linux-mint, mpich

I have manually downloaded and installed MPICH from [MPICH.org](http://www.mpich.org) using the [cookbook](http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.2/mpich-3.2-installguide.pdf) starting from section 2.2. But now I want to remove it. Does anybody have an idea how to uninstall it correctly, so I can reinstall another version? I have googled but have not found an answer that I can use.
"sudo apt-get remove mpich" doesn't remove the manually installed version.

My OS is Linux Mint 17.1, and the mpich version is 3.2

I don't think I can use this thread [Ubuntu 12.04 and MPICH performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402453/ubuntu-12-04-and-mpich-performance)

Comment: Did you compile it from sources? If so, did you try `make uninstall`?

Comment: I used the quick-installation in this guide http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.2/mpich-3.2-installguide.pdf , so I guess my answer is yes. From which directory should I run "make uninstall"?

Comment: From where you typed `make install`

Comment: I went to the directory of the unpacked the .tar-file and did 'make uninstall', and it worked I hope. But the install took a long time processing and the uninstall was pretty quick. As far as I can see the all it did was it removed the files from the directory.

Comment: It's normal it was fast. I think that's problem solved

Comment: I hope so, thanks. Is there a way to check it it's completely uninstalled?

Comment: What were **exactly** your installation command? Something like `tar xvfz mpich-3.2.tar.gz` then `cd mpich-3.2` then `./configure` then `make` then `make install`? Could you please update your question with this information as this is kind of essential to tell you the exact way of making sure you removed everything.

Comment: Yes that was how I did it. But my problem is kinda not important anymore. I installed openMPI and it works fine. So the old install of MPI doesn't interfere with openMPI, which was my worry.